# How to call ajax on fly for implementing pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript code having class named as PurchaseHistory.

```
var baseUrl = null;
var parameters = null;
var currentPageNumber = null;
var TotalPages = null;
var PageSize = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    baseUrl = "http://localhost/API/service.svc/GetOrderHistory";
    parameters = '{"userId":1 , "page":1 ,"pageSize":4}';
    currentPageNumber = 1;
    var history = new PurchaseHistory();
    history.ajaxCall(parameters);
});

function PurchaseHistory() {
/* On ajax error show error message
-------------------------------------------------*/
this.onAjaxError = function() {
    $('#error').text('No internet connection.').css('color', 'red');
}

/* Ajax call 
-------------------------------------------------*/
this.ajaxCall = function (parameters) {
    $.support.core = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl,
        data: parameters,
        //dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        error: function () { this.onAjaxError() }
    }).done(function (data) {
        var json = data.GetOrderHistoryResult;
        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(json);
        var history = new PurchaseHistory();
        history.populateOrderHistory(jsonObject);
        TotalPages = jsonObject.PgCnt;
        currentPageNumber = jsonObject.CrntPg;
    });
}

this.populateOrderHistory = function(results) {
    var rowOutput = "";
    var his = new PurchaseHistory();
    for (var i = 0; i < results.Results.length; i++) {
        rowOutput += this.renderCartList(results.Results[i], 1);
    }
}

this.renderCartList = function(res, i) {
    var container = $('#prototype-listelement>li').clone();
    container.find('.order-date').text(res.OdrDate);
    container.find('.item-count').text(res.Qty);
    container.find('.total').text(res.Amt);
    container.find('.order-id').text(res.OdrId);
    $('#mainul').append(container).listview('refresh');
}

this.loadNextPage = function () {
    parameters = '{"userId":1 , "page":' + currentPageNumber + 1 + ',"pageSize":4}';
    this.ajaxCall(parameters);
}
```

}

The ajaxCall is made on the ready function of the javascript.
This ajax calls returns Json object with pages information, which includes current page number, total pages and page size.

Currently I am able to display the information on the UI, when the page gets loaded.

My Issue:-
I want to call the ajax method again, on the button click event.
How this can be made possible and where can I store the information obtained from previous ajax call?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide with the html code where you are calling the function.

Comment: can you simplify it down to a small example?

Answer (score 0):

For pagination I would create a link that will load more items onto the page, and save a starting number to pass to your data layer. This example loads 20 at a time.

```
<a class="more" href="#" data-start="0">show more</a>

$("a.more").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var start = $(this).attr('data-start');

 $.get('/more-data, { start: start }, function(d){
   var next = start+20;
   $("a.more").attr('data-start', next);

   //process results here, do something with 'd'

 });
});
```